# Can I change the difficulty in Metal Gear Rising?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

Is there a way to change the difficulty level in Metal Gear Rising? I looked through the options screen but didn't see anything that looked like a difficulty setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to change the difficulty once you started a game.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the difficulty when selecting a chapter to play from the main menu
you can also set difficulty by selecting new game but this will RESET ALL YOUR UPGRADES